# How to generate clear graph with jgrapht with very big number of vertices that don't overlap each other

Tags: java, graph, jframe, jgrapht, jgraph

I am working on generating a graph with Java using jgraph and jgrapht libraries. The problem is that my graph has a very big number of vertices (varying from 300 to 1000 in some cases) and no matter what I try, vertices and edges keep on overlapping each other creating a mess and, of course, a non-readable graph. The method I used until now for placing the vertices on the JFrame is using random numbers as coordinates. Is there some other way to make this work? Maybe a better working algorithm or another Java library for better results?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We are currently having the same issue . Our graphs can also be extremely big . Using random number co-ordinates to generate the graph does not seem to be such a good idea ( Just my opinion ).  I have been using the graphiz library to generate graphs . It can handle fairly large graphs without them overlapping each other . You can check it out [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Home.php)

Depending on the type of graph you want can select one of graph algorithms ( dot,neato , fdp ,etc) Check out their [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) as well

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried Graphviz and the result is considerably better.

Comment: @cheflora thats excellent to hear . We still would want to make the whole visualization better . It would be interesting to hear if you are able to get a very good UI . Would like to hear about that . Cheers